# Android bug: DateFormat() sometimes shows 12hr format, when it should show 24hr format

Tags: java, android, time, format

I use the following code:

```
private long stampAsCal;
private DateFormat formatDateTime, formatDateTimeWSeconds, formatTimeOnly;
formatDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
formatDateTimeWSeconds = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());
formatTimeOnly = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
```

and

```
    return formatDateTimeWSeconds.format(stampAsCal);
```

I normally get a String like:

```
05.06.2018 22:00:48
```

but in some occasions I get

```
05.06.2018 10:00:48 nachm.
```

instead

What is going wrong here?

---

The phone is a Moto Z Play with Android 7.1.1

My language setting is German (Germany).

My Date time settings are:

- Auto date/time (network)
- Auto Time zone (network)
- 24 hr format active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that area had a couple of issue, most of which are [described here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37054851). All known ones are fixed in newer Android releases, but that won't help enough in that specific case.

One suggested workaround is to check `is24HourFormat` in your code:

```
boolean use24Hour = android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context); 
final String skeleton = use24Hour ? "Hm" : "hm"; 
final String pattern = android.text.format.DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(locale, skeleton);
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale);
```

Adapt the skeleton as necessary to get the desired format.

Comment: This seems to be the exact root cause behind my problem. However, since .getBestDateTimePattern() was introduced with API18 and I use API 15 upwards, I need to study my options further.
But thanks a lot for the hint so far, I will report back

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks a lot to Joachim Sauer for identifying the problem and finding the solution.

---

In case anybody would like this to work also for pre-API18, here's how I decided to handle the Android bug:

```
    boolean use24Hour = android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(MainActivity.getContext());
    if (use24Hour && formatDateTimeWSeconds instanceof SimpleDateFormat) {
         String pattern = ((SimpleDateFormat) formatDateTimeWSeconds).toPattern();
        if (pattern.contains("h")) {
            pattern = pattern.replace("hh", "HH").replace("h", "HH").replace(" a", "").replace("a", "");
            formatDateTimeWSeconds = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.getDefault());
        }
    }
```